# How to reinstall Safari 8 without reinstalling OS X Yosemite

Tags: safari, macos, crash

Safari keeps on crashing or is unusable for some other reason and I have no possibility of reinstalling it without reinstalling the OS. What do I do?

Comment: You can download  the latest safari for yosemite, mavericks and mountain lion here: http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Safari.shtml 
After you downloaded it just install it and safari will work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First try to boot your computer into Safe Mode and open Safari. If it does open you can see if there are any extensions causing the crash and remove them.

You can also update to the Safari 8.0.1 beta from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action# and see if that helps fix it.

If all else fails. Boot to the recovery partition and reinstall the OS (This will ONLY reinstall the core system and its Apps. Including Safari. No personal data will be lost)

Comment: Can you describe in bit more detail how to do the last solution?

Comment: Better solution than mine, but sadly too late to try out :) Maybe (hopefully never) next time!

Answer (score 0):

Steps to take to reinstall Safari:

1. Remove Safari with `Clean My Mac` (or something similar, simply
   dragging it to the trash doesn't work)
2. Ask a friend/colleague (someone you trust not to have adapted the file) to upload his Safari to a server or dropbox (or something similar)
3. Download the just-uploaded Safari
4. Drag it from your download-folder to your `Applications`
5. Enjoy Safari 8

Comment: I would not suggest doing this for many reasons, not the least of which is software piracy. Removing a core system component and replacing it, even with the same version, is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sadly, it was too late for me to try something else (in some way, I couldn't get into safe mode) and this solved it for me.

Comment: @tubedogg Dude, we're talking about Safari! A browser, not a program which costs money!

Comment: ...what does that have to do with anything? The license agreement requires you not to distribute it. The amount you paid for it is not relevant to whether or not it is piracy and against the license agreement.

Answer (score -2):

This post solved my Safari problem (crashing on opening):

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203987

DO NOT install ANY software from developers you don't know! Belatedly, I learned you can set Safari's preferences so you're forewarned. I was working late New Year's Day, was tired, and really didn't want to be there. While using Photoshop, a notification popped-up saying something to the effect that "this program wants to install an update . . ." Naturally, I thought it was an Adobe update and rather absent-mindedly clicked okay. Bad mistake. The culprit turned out to be an ad-injection software known as "Genieo." (There are several others). I spent the next two days trying to solve the problem when I finally stumbled across the above Apple support post.